# Unable to run the asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Whenever trying to run the asp.net web application it's showing this error on browser :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       The resource cannot be found.
>       Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>       Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2556.0

I tried to change the port, created virtual directory and same code is running on other system.

Comment: How are you running the site; through Visual Studio (IIS Express) or hosted in IIS? What URL is the site running at? What technology does the site use (Webforms, MVC, other...)? What does your Global.asax file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a default document in this location such as : index.htm, default.aspx etc? Since you are requesting '/' it is looking for a default document which it is not finding obviously.

Answer (score 0):

meaning of 404 error: specified document/file/filepath does not resides on server. I would thinking of checking exact spelling + extension of it.  Server had no chance to reply on your request